# jQuery: How to destroy or reset a plugin

Tags: jquery, css

To preface this, I hope it's possible to get a general answer to this question on best practice on how to accomplish something like this, as well as a possible answer to my specific ask?

I have been working on a "prove you are human" plugin and I have it working when everything loads.  I am using jQuery UI as it's backbone and am using Draggable and Droppable.  The general question is: How do I destroy and reset a plugin on an event?  The more specific question is: When I drag the wrong object onto the spot, how can I reset the ability to drag and drop after everything is destroyed.

Below is pseudo code:

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.robotProof = function(options){
        var defaults = {
            //Default variables
        }

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function(defaults){
        /* Here I style the elements because they were not styled by a CSS
           Then I randomly assign the elements a spot and append them to the container
           Then I use Draggable and Droppable */

        $('.peg').draggable({
            drag: function() {
                /* Drag Function Here */
            },
            revert: 'invalid'
        });
        $('.hole').droppable ({
            accept: '.valid',
            drop: function(){
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                if(!username || !email || !password){ //IF ONE OF THE INPUTS IS EMPTY
                    $('.hardError').html("You've forgotten something").slideDown(300);
                    //////* THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO DESTROY/RESET THIS PLUGIN *//////////       
                } else {                        
                    $('.valid').animate({left: "286px",top: "1px"});//success
                }
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.robotProof').robotProof();
});
```

You can see in the droppable code, on the error (This will be on ALL errors eventually) I need to be able to RESET the plugin.

I feel like (and have played with this idea) that almost the entire code needs to be a function so I can call the function again.  When I tried that, I had to then nest the code because it wouldn't allow the elements to be draggable again, unless I put those elements in the function as well, which would then call it's own function, which we all know doesn't work like that.

I have written a couple successful plugins before, but this is a question I have had throughout every one of them.  How can I destroy all instances of this then reset the plugin without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have fun with it. :) looks like i had to much time, but this does what you want.
So the clue is to overwrite your jQuery-function with

**`$.fn.robotProof={}`**

You see its also possible to restart and start-over with complete differnet function content

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
(function($){
    $.fn.SelfDestroy=function(blabla){
        function init(){
            var brutal = 'mega conspirative content of your plugin :)';
            $('#report').text(brutal);
        };
        init();
        return this.each(function(){
           $('#counter').text('ding dong'+i).show().fadeOut(200);
           i++;
           $(this).text(blabla);
        });
    };
    $.fn.Destroy=function(){
        // lets overwrite the jQuery plugin function
        $.fn.SelfDestroy={};
    };
    $.fn.Rebuild=function(){
        // here we load other work in the same namespace as before
        $.fn.SelfDestroy=function(ZoroZonk){
           if (ZoroZonk=='push to test if stil running') 
           $('#report').text('my name is bond, james bond').show().fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#bomb').on('click',function(){
       $().Destroy();
       $().Rebuild();
   });
   $('#report').SelfDestroy('huaaa! time to run! but stil original function work');
});
</script>

<button id="selfdestroytester" onclick="$(this).SelfDestroy('push to test if stil running')">check if valid running code</button>
<div id="report"> placeholder for output </div>
<button id="bomb" onclick="">push to start selfdestroy!</button>
<div id="counter" style="display:none"> hitcounter </div>
```

Comment: As I read through, I believe you are saying create separate functions for each 'event', destroy being one of them, then when it needs to destroy, run that event, rebuild the code and run it again?  I will definitely try this.  I also really enjoy your enthusiastic code/content!

Comment: it is posible to reset the plugin inside the plugin itsself. you just have to beware of calling functions on it after its allready destroyed but not rebuilded/reloaded.. made of this it is not existing anymore or overwritten, so you had to overwrite it again to `reinit/rebuild` its behavior. and this must be placed outside of the destroyed mechanism. sure! :)

Comment: so clever would be, to overwrite the original `$.fn.robotProof` with a recall in it which calls a function who reloads a **new** `$.fn.*` and destroys with this the recall function again. its like destroying twice. but it is recalling once, because you could build it so that it will reload it with the first call by its nature. O.o

Comment: but again this is just like smashing the namespace in the recyclebin and rebuilding it, where i dont get to understand who this makes things saver :)

Answer (score 1):

Destroying a plugin means reverting the added behavior, that is removing both draggable and droppable behavior from the affected elements.

Both the [droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-destroy) and [draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy) plugins provide a destroy method to revert the changes made.

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.robotProof = function(options){
        var defaults = {
            //Default variables
        }

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function(defaults){
            var _this = this;
        /* Here I style the elements because they were not styled by a CSS
           Then I randomly assign the elements a spot and append them to the container
           Then I use Draggable and Droppable */

        $('.peg').draggable({
            drag: function() {
                /* Drag Function Here */
            },
            revert: 'invalid'
        });
        $('.hole').droppable ({
            accept: '.valid',
            drop: function(){
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                if(!username || !email || !password){ //IF ONE OF THE INPUTS IS EMPTY
                    $('.hardError').html("You've forgotten something").slideDown(300);
                    //////* THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO DESTROY/RESET THIS PLUGIN *//////////       

                    //In this case destroy meanns reverting the added behaviour, that is removing both draggable and droppable behaviour from the affected elements
                    $('.peg').draggable('destroy');
                    $('.hole').droppable('destroy');
                } else {                        
                    $('.valid').animate({left: "286px",top: "1px"});//success
                }
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.robotProof').robotProof();
});
```

Comment: but anyway i try to figure out where this concept is robotProof. intressting thing. because robots fill input fields it would be possible to hide a inputfield via css and analyse at server side that nothing is in this field, ..if not empty, a robot was working.

Comment: In this case, there is no input field, and a person would have to write a desktop script to be able to click and drag a random element to the matching element.  Those programmers are far and few between for how not-popular this site will be

Comment: @Arun P Johny, This somewhat answers a small part of this problem.  I have not read about the destroy with draggable and droppable and I will look further into that.  The reason I would like to reset this entire plugin (along with any other plugin) is to reload any of the code.  In this particular case, it has a randomization, a styling and a placement that I would like to totally reset.  I will look into this answer more before I accept any answers.

Comment: which means you could reset/rebuild just your randomization code. nice!